# .to_excel function doesnt export any values

Tags: python, pandas

```
from pathlib import Path  # Core Python Module
import pandas as pd  # pip install pandas openpyxl
import xlwings as xw  # pip install xlwings
import numpy as np


df1 = pd.read_excel('spain.xlsx')
df_es = pd.DataFrame(df1, columns=['asini'])

df_es.to_excel('multiple.xlsx')
```

What i get after running the program is a excel file with no values. Looking forward to some solutions. Thanks!

p.s: same happens when i'm running this code:

```
df1 = pd.read_excel('italy.xlsx')
df_it = pd.DataFrame(df1, columns=['asini'])

df2 = pd.read_excel('spain.xlsx')
df_es = pd.DataFrame(df2, columns=['asini'])

compare = df_it.compare(df_es, align_axis=1, keep_shape=True, keep_equal=False)

compare.to_excel('multiple.xlsx')
```

Comment: So what output do you expect by `df_es = pd.DataFrame(df1, columns=['asini'])`

Comment: the whole 3rd column of the excel document

Comment: Please do some formatting.

Comment: You said “the whole 3rd column of the excel document”, so the column index of the 3rd column is 'asini'?

Comment: yes,the index is 'asini'

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a .values() function or  DataFrame.to_numpy() is what you need. Actually you can't directly use a dataframe object to generate a datafram object. Use numpy() or dict() or etc.

Besides the `columns` parameter should match the selected numpy array.